# Gradle : cannot copy file

Tags: file, gradle, copy

I try to copy a file with gradle.
There is no problem to create a file, scan a directory but the copy of file doesnt work

```
task toDo3{
    println("task toDo3 start in $projectDir" )

    new File("$projectDir/version.txt").text =
            """
                Version: $version
                Revision: 1.0.2
                Buildtime: ${new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())}
                Application-name: foobarbaz app
            """
    println("task toDo3 end" )
}

task toDo4(type: Copy) {
    println("task toDo4 start" )
    from "src/main/version.txt"
    into "build"
    println("task toDo4 end" )
}
```

Any idea about this problem ?

Thank for help

Comment: You create the file in `$projectDir` but then copy from `src/main` which are different directories.

Comment: Also, your task toDo3 does its work during the configuration phase rather than doing it in the execution phase. So the file is always being created, whether or not you execute toDo3. All its code should be in a doLast {} block.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to understand [Gradle's build phases](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases)

All of your println statements are in the configuration phase when it's likely you want them to fire in the execution phase. Your toDo3 does everything in the configuration phase and nothing in the execution phase.

You'll likely want to put your println's etc in a `doFirst {...}` or a `doLast{...}` closure

It's also bad practice to generate files under `src/main`. It's better practice to generate under $buildDir so the files:

1. Are deleted by the "clean" task
2. Aren't accidentally committed to source control
3. Don't impact Gradle's up-to-date checking / task skipping